# Python Flask ajax POST 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: python, ajax, flask, request

I am trying to send data from a form to Python Flask using ajax. I do not want the page to reload. When I try to send the form I get the error
`POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/addTran 400 (BAD REQUEST)`

I just want to input a Russian word with an English translation and then to write it to a file from flask.
Here is my html and JavaScript

```
<form id="translationForm">
  <label for="russianWord">Russian Word:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="russianWord" serialize-as="russianWord" name="russianWord"><br>
  <label for="englishWord">English word:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="englishWord" serialize-as="englishWord" name="englishWord">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#translationForm').on('submit',function (e) {

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{url_for('addTran')}}",
                data: $('#translationForm').serialize(),
                contentType: "application/j-son;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                 alert("It worked!");
                }
              });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Here is my Python route

```
@app.route('/addTran',methods=["POST"])
def addTran():
    if request.method == "POST":
        tran = request.get_json(force=True)
        with open('/home/matt/Desktop/info.txt','w') as w:
            w.write(str(tran))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding JSON.stringify() worked!
`data: JSON.stringify($('#translationForm').serialize())`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the typo in the request content type?

```
contentType: "application/j-son;charset=UTF-8",
```

To

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

Comment: Thanks but no dice

Comment: What do the request and response look like? Do you see them in the browser network monitor and in the server logs? Is JSON being posted or form data? It would be easier to debug with some runnable server code.

Comment: Does the .sterilize() turn the form data into json? I'm very new to this so I dont have server logs

Comment: The words that I input into the form are not showing up in the url like they are supposed to

Comment: The problem appears to be with this line `tran = request.get_json(force=True)` after replacing it with `tran = 'whatever'` it worked

Comment: Sounds like you're going to write `'whatever'` to the file, not what you got from the json. You should check from your browser if the request sent to the server is valid using https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ and also - you should print out whatever exception is thrown on the server side and look at it. You shouldn't try and develop with logs, it's like developing blindly.